# React native cameraWithTensors onReady is only called when file is saved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tensorflow.js

cameraWithTensors is supposed to start sending frames from the incoming video to a function that handles the camera input. The issue is that the function only gets called when I navigate to the page and save the code once again, without this the function never gets called. It is weird as there are no errors being logged.

**cameraWithTensor frames are passed to handleCameraStream**

```
        <TensorCamera
          style={styles.camera}
          type={type}
          zoom={0}
          cameraTextureHeight={textureDimsState.height}
          cameraTextureWidth={textureDimsState.width}
          resizeHeight={tensorDims.height}
          resizeWidth={tensorDims.width}
          resizeDepth={tensorDims.depth}
          onReady={imageAsTensors => handleCameraStream(imageAsTensors)}
          autorender={AUTORENDER}
        />
```

**handleCameraStream takes as input the frame from TensorCamera and continuously loops making predictions on the frames**

**blazeFaceModel and loadedModel are set with null initially and when the both models are loaded I set their values from useEffect()**

```
  const handleCameraStream = imageAsTensors => {
    if (!imageAsTensors) {
      console.log("Image not found!");
    }
    const loop = async () => {
      const imageTensor = imageAsTensors.next().value;

      if (loadedModel !== null && blazeFaceModel !== null) {
        console.log("Started");
        await getPrediction(imageTensor).catch(e => console.log(e));
      }
      tf.dispose(imageAsTensors);
      requestAnimationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
    //loop infinitely to constantly make predictions
    loop();
  };
```

**useEffect() contains the data I need to set initially, loadedModel and blazeFaceModel are set here**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!frameWorkReady) {
      (async () => {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync().catch(e =>
          console.log(e)
        );
        if (Platform.OS == "ios") {
          setTextureDims({ height: 1920, width: 1080 });
        } else {
          setTextureDims({ height: 1200, width: 1600 });
        }
        setHasPermission(status === "granted");
        await tf.ready().catch(e => console.log(e));
        setTFReady(true);
        setModelLoaded(await loadModel().catch(e => console.log(e)));
        setBlazeFaceModel(
          await loadBlazeFaceModel().catch(e => console.log(e))
        );
        setFrameWorkReady(true);
      })();
    }
  }, []);
```

I thought about just adding a button to refresh the page but I would prefer if I did not have to do that.